# Django ModelForm encode and instance error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working with `Django ModelForms` and I got some problems with the Admin Form override. I created the next code to change the widget of my multichoice field.

```
media_outlet = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    label= _(u'Media outlet'), 
    queryset=MediaOutlet.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
)
```

when I saved, I get this error: `UnicodeDecodeError`. Is there a way to validate or define the encode? and this another error when I select others value: `"Entry.media_outlet" must be a "MediaOutlet" instance`.

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  551.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  224.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1508.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1408.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1440.             if form.is_valid():

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  386.         self._post_clean()

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  403.             self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in construct_instance
  65.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in save_form_data
  853.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)

File "/Users/lebel/WebProjects/mediacorruption/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  216.                     self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/dc_report/entry/add/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the Model

```
class Country(models.Model):

    iso = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class MediaOutlet(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

class Entry(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date")
    case_desc = models.TextField(verbose_name="Case Description")
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True)
    media_outlet = models.ForeignKey(MediaOutlet, null=True)
```

Any idea whats it's happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, show the full traceback. You probably have an error in the MediaOutlook `__str__` or `__unicode__` method, so you should show that too.

Comment: You didn't post the model methods as I asked.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the model. I change the models to ManyToManyField and the problem fix it.